# Ubuntu 17.04 + Netgear WNA 1100 (Atheros AR9271) - Wifi Networks Visible but not connecting

Tags: networking, usb, atheros, netgear

I am running Ubuntu-17.04 via a 16-GB bootable USB. Ubuntu is not installed on the usb or the disk.
HP ProDesk desktop computer, without Wifi. I am using a NetGear WNA 1100 (Atheros AR9271) USB dongle.

I am able to see all the Wifi SSIDs, but when I enter password, and try to connect, it does not. 
Presently I am using my phone via USB tethering.

```
> sudo apt-get update   
> sudo apt-get upgrade   
> sudo service network-manager restart
```

Also, did not help me connect to wifi. 
I have also installed the **ath9k_htc-installer_1-0-4.deb** from https://sourceforge.net/projects/ath9k-htc/files/ath9k_htc-installer/ as recommend on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsWirelessNetworkCardsNetgear#USB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer to this.

```
sudo vi /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

add

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

end of the file and save it.
restart service networking and NetworkManager

worked on live-usb
worked on installed