# Bluetooth not detected with rfkill list on dell xps from fresh install

Tags: network-manager, bluetooth, dell

when i pull up bluetooth the toggle button is disabled.

```
description: Wireless interface
   product: BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC
   vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlp2s0
   version: 01
   serial: 44:1c:a8:e2:e6:75
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmfmac driverversion=7.35.177.61 firmware=01-ea662a8c ip=10.0.0.79 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:137 memory:dd800000-dd807fff memory:dd400000-dd7fffff

[sudo] password for me:
```

● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working) you should be able to find the firmware file at https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/tree/master/brcm   Actually edit the post to include results from terminal for `lsusb`

Answer (score 0):

From: [Turn Bluetooth on or off](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/bluetooth-turn-on-off.html.en)

You can turn Bluetooth on to connect to other Bluetooth devices, or turn it off to conserve power. To turn Bluetooth on:

- Open the Activities overview and start typing `Bluetooth`.
- Click on Bluetooth to open the panel.
- Set the switch at the top to `ON`.

Many laptop computers have a hardware switch or key combination to turn Bluetooth on and off. Look for a switch on your computer or a key on your keyboard. The keyboard key is often accessed with the help of the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key.

---

From this answer:

- [Ubuntu 18.04 wireless connections visible but won't connect BCM43602](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091172/ubuntu-18-04-wireless-connections-visible-but-wont-connect-bcm43602)

You can try:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt update
sudo update-pciids
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer
sudo reboot #note that this will restart your computer
sudo iwconfig wlp2s0 txpower 10dBm
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to be the issue with my laptop. Its not recognizing any bluetooth adapter.

Comment: Does the Wi-Fi connect to networks? I've updated the answer.

Comment: it does connect to networks just no bluetooth functionality.

Comment: my output looks simmilar but instead of active it says dead

Comment: `[sudo] password for me: 
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)`